# Problems to validate pattern in decimal number in formcontrol angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have problem with validate pattern in formBuilder , my locale configuration is 'es' accept number ',' as decimal separator.

**HTML**

```
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label class="control-label">
                        <i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i> Precio</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm " formControlName="txtPrecio" [(ngModel)]="itemDetalle.precio" />
                    <small [hidden]="itemForm.controls.txtPrecio.valid || (itemForm.controls.txtPrecio.pristine && !itemForm.controls.submitted)" class="text-danger">
                            <div [hidden]="!itemForm.controls.txtPrecio.hasError('required')">Campo obligatorio</div>
                            <div [hidden]="!itemForm.controls.txtPrecio.hasError('minlength')">Mínimo 1 digito</div>
                            <div [hidden]="!itemForm.controls.txtPrecio.hasError('maxlength')">Mínimo 10 digito</div>
                            <div [hidden]="!itemForm.controls.txtPrecio.hasError('pattern')">(txtPrecio) sólo números con 6 decimales separados coma (,) </div>                                                                                 
                    </small>

                </div>
```

**Component**

```
constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder ,private toastr: ToastrService) {

  this.itemForm = this.formBuilder.group({     
  'txtCant' : ['', Validators.compose([ Validators.maxLength(20),Validators.pattern('[0-9]+(\,[0-9]{0,3}?)?')])],
  'txtConcepto' : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  'txtUnidad' : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  'txtPrecio' : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(20),Validators.pattern('[0-9]+(\,[0-9]{0,3}?)?')])],
  'txtImporte' : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(20),Validators.pattern('[0-9]+(\,[0-9]{0,3}?)?')])]      
  });


  this.itemForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      //  console.log('this.cabeceraForm.statusChanges');

    if ( this.itemForm.valid ) {
       console.log('this.itemForm.statusChanges isValid true');
      this.isValid.emit(true);
    } else {
      console.log('this.itemForm.statusChanges isValid false');
      this.isValid.emit(false);
    }
  });
}
```

When write input with values :

1,222 = has error of pattern ( model value = 1.222 is OK)

1.33 = has error of pattern

but if I change input type = "text" with the values :

1,222 =Ok  ( model value = NaN )

1.33 = has error of pattern

So just validate "Ok" if the input type is "text" , but in the model obtain "NaN" value.

Thanks!!

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I didin't find a solution , I changed my local configuration to En (default) and use dot (.) as a decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

Change you regex and try this

```
\d+([.]\d+)?
```

Comment: the same problem ! :(

Comment: impossible https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ve1kcs  in order to trigger validation you have to type something into inputs.

Comment: I going to probe with Angular 6

Comment: Validators.pattern('\\d+([.]\\d+)?')
insted of
Validators.pattern('\d+([.]\d+)?')
the point is double slash